# SSD + HDD partitioning

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, steam

I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 on a HDD and I recently bought a 120GB SSD.

I'll make a clean install with `/` on the SSD, but I'm not sure if I should put `/home` on the SSD or the HDD.

I'd like, for instance, to have my steam games installed on the SSD, but I would prefer to have my media files (and other programs) on the HDD.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `~/` is the home directory of the current user (most shells expand `~` at the beginning of words to the value of `$HOME`). Do you mean `/`, the root directory, instead?

Comment: Yeah, i meant the root partition, but I think askubuntu edited my message automatically :(

Comment: I never noticed AU adding random `~` characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Steam settings, you can manually specify a library location, or you can select a different (or create a different) library when you install a game on a game-by-game basis.

I would recommend just formatting both as `ext4` in the installer, and just do Steam on the SSD.

EDIT: You could also add `/bin` and `/usr` to the SSD, as that will improve performance and speed in both day-to-day operation as well as booting up, as most programs are run out of those directories (mostly /usr).

Comment: A better idea would be to put /bin and /usr on the SSD so the computer would boot faster and most programs load from the SSD.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste depends on his steam library size, I'll add it to my answer

Comment: Steam will also rely on some system packages, so having `/` on a SSD might help with performance

Comment: @Wilf The majority of the packages that Steam is reliant on are in `/bin` and `/usr`, so having the whole `/` on the SSD would just be a waste of space, especially since it is only 120 Gb